# Софт для автоматического рисования схемы БД Oracle

Tags: база-данных, oracle, поиск-программ

Подскажите бесплатный софт которым можно автоматически нарисовать схему существующей БД Oracle. Что-то на подобии Sysbase PowerDesigner, но бесплатное.

Comment: Предлагаемое ораклом средство должно уметь по идее. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/datamodeler/overview/index.html  лицензию там почитайте но как все у оракла для разрабочиков долно быть свободно доступно

Comment: То что надо. Оформите ответом, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У Oracle есть свое средство "SQL Developer Data Modeler", доступное для свободного скачивания на сайте oracle.com. В текущий момент по [Этой ссылке](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/datamodeler/overview/index.html).

Данное средство идет под лицензией "OTN License", которая разрешает свободное использование продукта в целях разработки, тестирования, прототипирования, демонстрации.